# How do I quickly edit duplicate data in a single cell in Excel?

Tags: excel

I got an Excel document from a colleague but the initial field is duplicate that is to say:

```
Name
Entry1 Entry1
Entry2 Entry2
and so on...
```

I am manually changing them at the moment but for later reference is there a way to manipulate records cell by cell that will either remove the Entry[space] or [space]Entry.
Again, I am just curious for future reference in case I run into this again.

Edit: To clarify on the data:
Some of the cells in the 'Name' field are one name with spaces, some names have non-letter characters in them and so on ie. Mary Anne, D'juan, etc.

Comment: So there is a space separating the first occurrence and the last occurrence but there may be spaces within each occurrence  ...? e.g. there would always be an odd number of spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an unused column to the right, put this formula into the second row,

```
=LEFT(A2, FIND(CHAR(215), SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", CHAR(215), INT((LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, " ", "")))/2)+1))-1)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: entry1_entry1]